# Wordpress and Woocommerce - unable to add gallery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a strange issue when trying to open the media modal from a woocommerce product.

Basically, the modal just won't show up.

I am running a fresh install of Wordpress (**v4.6.1**) and WooCommerce. The theme is a custom theme (with correct woocommerce declaration on my functions.php file)

I' ve already tried the following:

- Disable all the plugins - Still not working
- Revert theme - Still not working
- Change permalinks for both Posts and Products - Still not working
- Create new products - Still not working

And checked the following:

- dev console - no errors are thrown
- apache2 error log - again, clear, no errors.
- apache2 access log - no errors, still all clear.

Something odd I've noticed, is the actual link:

When I click on add product gallery, the page refreshes because the link is the following:

```
"http://10.254.237.107/wp-admin/post.php?post=9675&action=edit"
```

while if I try to add a featured picture (that opens the same modal) the link is correct and the modal shows up correctly:

```
"http://10.254.237.107/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=9675&type=image&TB_iframe=1"
```

Do you have any idea why this happens? and how to solve it, or maybe how to debug it a bit more deeply?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue related, somehow, with woocommerce. I installed a new one and it fixed itself.